# ODBC driver (AcuODBC, MS Access Driver)

Tags: odbc, windows-7-x64

hi i've developed a java descktop application (in Windows 7) that use
ms access and cobol db...

to use that db i've two odbc sources data that are:

***Microsoft Access Driver ODBC** (for my .mdb file)

******AcuODBC** (for cobol db).

Now i've canged pc and in my ODBC manager i don't have the driver to create
a data sources. (my new OS is Win7 X64)

Can you tell me where can i download the 2 drivers?

Thx you ALL

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to download new drivers, you just need to use the 32 bit version of the ODBC administrator found in:

```
%windir%\syswow64\odbcad32.exe
```

The ODBC administrator in the control panel is the 64 bit version which won't show any 32 bit drivers.  If your application is 32 bit then you need a 32 bit dsn created in the 32 bit ODBC administrator.

Comment: thx for answer but, nothing...
i see only Sql Server Drivers...
Some ideas?

Comment: nope sorry that's all i have, i've never seen a system where the access driver isn't in the 32bit odbc administrator.  Are you sure you tried the one in syswow64?